# Не отображается папка Tables в public DataGrip

Tags: datagrip

DataGrip 2018.1.2

Раньше в schemas/public была папка с таблица

Сейчас вижу только sequencese & object types

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В чём может быть проблема

Comment: Для начала проверим: вот тут они не выключены? https://imgur.com/KiEkrGo